# Problem with AWS signature version 4 using Boto3 to send email

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses

I'm trying to send an email using Django 2.2 and Boto3 (v 1.17.72) through SES. I created a new SMTP Credential (following this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-credentials.html) and called the Boto3 service:

```
client = boto3.client('ses',
region_name=settings.AWS_SES_REGION_NAME,
aws_access_key_id=settings.AWS_SES_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
aws_secret_access_key=settings.AWS_SES_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
```

But when the applications try to send the email AWS return me this error message:

***The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.***

Could anyone help me to know how to fix it please?
Thank you in advance,

Andre.

Comment: what region are you trying to use?

Comment: In addition to maybe being in the wrong region, also try out: `config=Config(signature_version="s3v4")` in the client kwargs where `Config` is from `from botocore.client import Config`

Comment: @JDD my region is sa-east-1.

Comment: @acw I have not problem with S3, cause it's working well with signature version 4. I am having problema with SES when I try to send email using boto3 with django_ses lib.

Comment: @acw I tried this right now but same error.

Comment: @Anndreh I didn't know you were using django-ses. In that case, take a look at this commit: https://github.com/Donate-Anything/Donate-Anything/commit/0888dfd0c2001c89e24beb6c6d9dc45264e33180#diff-4babd923ec3b84659a9e87c242f3b8df5cf72f4ca80db4377b0cdd02bffda0ef